# serialize class to identifier (offset in array)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Basically I want classes that behave like enums when serialized/deserialized, where these operations only saves/loads an identifier. when one of these objects are serialized, I want to save an integer to file. When I deserialize, I want to read this integer under the hood, use it as an offset in a static array and the resulting object will be the instance which the array contains. can this be done?

Comment: yes, you can use the `ordinal()` or better, an id you have assigned to each enum.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have this:

```
public class COMMODITY implements Serializable{

    static COMMODITY[] cs = new COMMODITY[]{
            new COMMODITY("hello", 0),
            new COMMODITY("hello2", 1)
    };

    final int index;
    final transient String name;
    final transient int two = 2;

    COMMODITY(String name, int index){
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException{
          return cs[index];
    }

}
```

And it gives me what I want. However, I'd like a better way